# Example box with automatic numbering?

Tags: numbering, boxes, framed, examples

Working with [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), I was just wondering how do you create a box around a set of related text such as an example in a textbook? I found `\framebox` or `\makebox`, but I can't figure out how to make it auto number such as Example 1.1 (for first example in chapter 1), or even manually add to it.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the [`ntheorem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem), [`shadethm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shadethm) and [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) packages, all of which let you define new environments in boxes with numbering.

Answer (score 3):

Put it in an environment, like the `listings` package mentioned above, or you can define your own environment that will get its own counter:

```
 \newenvironment{nam}[args]{begdef}{enddef}

\renewenvironment{nam}[args]{begdef}{enddef}
```

These commands define or redefine an environment.

`nam` --
    The name of the environment. For `\newenvironment` there must be no currently defined environment by that name, and the command `\nam` must be undefined. For `\renewenvironment` the environment must already be defined.

`args` --
    An integer from 1 to 9 denoting the number of arguments of the newly-defined environment. The default is no arguments.

`begdef` -- 
    The text substituted for every occurrence of `\begin{nam}`; a parameter of the form `#n` in `cmd` is replaced by the text of the nth argument when this substitution takes place.

`enddef` --
    The text substituted for every occurrence of `\end{nam}`. It may not contain any argument parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.
I don't know how much it is suited for other than programming languages, but I think it is adaptable. Are your examples code listings? Anyway, here is an example:

```
\usepackage{listings}
...

\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Examples} % Label of Table of Listings
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Example} % Label for every Listing
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}
\lstset{frame=single,captionpos=b,basicstyle={\rmfamily}}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[short D.]long Description},language=ruby]
  array.each do |a|
    a.times { puts "Examples" }
  end
\end{lstlisting}
```

**Edit:**
For math there is an option `mathescape=true`, so formulas work inside single dollar signs.

Comment: My examples are mostly mathematics, its notes taking for math class. Thanks a lot!